# (ngModel)] input with default input values

Tags: angular

i've got an input field and i want so set default values. But with ngModel the input fields are just empty.
How do i set default values which the user can change?

```html
<div class="control">
 <input #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="message.name" name="name" class="input" type="text" value="{{data.name}}" required>
 <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="name.touched && name.invalid">This field is required</p>
</div>
 <button (click)="saveEdit()" [disabled]="!(name.valid)">Save</button>
```

i'm not very experienced in angular/webdev...

Thank you!

Solution:

Add

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.message.name = this.data.name
}
```

to ts.component

Comment: In `ngAfterViewInit()` you can set the `message.name` value and it will be bind in the `html input` field.

Comment: @Marco that worked perfectly. ty!

Comment: Can you accept the answer of @Shivansh Sethas it tells the same things as me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input [(ngModel)]="message.name" name="name" class="input" type="text" required>`

In your component :

`message : any = { name: 'YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE', }`

Comment: that solution is working. Im gonna keep this one instead of using the ngAfterViewInit(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input  [(ngModel)]="message" name="name" class="input" type="text"required>
```

In your Typescript file Add message = 'defaultvalue'

Comment: this one is not working because message is an object. See @Shivansh Seth solution, which is almost the same. TY!